# TestNG for starting database before test runs and stopping afterwards

Tags: testng

I am currently trying to run some test against a  mongoDB which i want to start via TestNG.

The suite should:

1. start a mongoDB instance (possible embedded or separate process)
2. run one or more tests (possibly in different classes or packages)
3. stop the mongoDB instance

I tried this:

```
<suite name="EmbeddedMongoSmokeTest" verbose="1">
<parameter name="mongoPort" value="27018"/>

<test name="EmbeddedMongoSmokeTest">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.frequentis.ps.platform.tests.persistence.EmbeddedMongoControllerTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="startEmbeddedMongoDb" />
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="com.frequentis.ps.platform.tests.persistence.MongoDBSmokeTest"/>
        <class name="com.frequentis.ps.platform.tests.persistence.EmbeddedMongoControllerTest">
            <methods>
                <include name="stopEmbeddedMongoDb" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

```
@Test(groups = { "persistence", "mongodb"})
public class EmbeddedMongoControllerTest {
    private static EmbeddedMongoController mongoController;

    @Test
    @Parameters({ "mongoHost", "mongoPort"})
    public void startEmbeddedMongoDb(@Optional("localhost") String host, @Optional("27017") int port) {
        mongoController = new EmbeddedMongoController();
        mongoController.start(host, port);
    }

    @Test
    public void stopEmbeddedMongoDb() {
        mongoController.stop();
    }
}
```

I get an exception from the TestNG runner which says "No free nodes found in:[DynamicGraph", I guess this comes from the fact that I use the same class twice in a single test section.

How am I supposed to structure my TestNG suite xml or what kind of TestNG feature shall I use to accomplish my task in a clean way?

Comment: Why not just use a singleton for it -would be lazy initialization as well?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look on [the TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).

BTW, as I understand your need, you want to start mongo before a group of tests and stop it after them.

You can use `@Before/AfterGroup("mongodb")` (but you'll have to activate the group because testng is not doing it even if a test is part of the group) or `@Before/AfterTest`.

```
public class EmbeddedMongoControllerTest {
    private static EmbeddedMongoController mongoController;

    @BeforeTest // or @BeforeGroup("mongodb")
    @Parameters({ "mongoHost", "mongoPort"})
    public void startEmbeddedMongoDb(@Optional("localhost") String host, @Optional("27017") int port) {
        mongoController = new EmbeddedMongoController();
        mongoController.start(host, port);
    }

    @AfterTest // @AfterGroup("mongodb")
    public void stopEmbeddedMongoDb() {
        mongoController.stop();
    }
}

<suite name="EmbeddedMongoSmokeTest" verbose="1">
  <parameter name="mongoPort" value="27018"/>

  <test name="EmbeddedMongoSmokeTest">
    <!--If @Before/AfterGroup usage <groups> 
      <run>
        <include name="mongodb"/>
      </run>
    </groups> -->

    <classes>
        <class name="com.frequentis.ps.platform.tests.persistence.EmbeddedMongoControllerTest">
        </class>
        <class name="com.frequentis.ps.platform.tests.persistence.MongoDBSmokeTest"/>
        </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
```

And you can remove `EmbeddedMongoControllerTest` from the list if `MongoDBSmokeTest extends EmbeddedMongoControllerTest`.

Comment: thanks, i did take a look at the docs but was blind to find something. Now I used ISuiteListener for it but I will also try your approach.

Comment: Keep your listener. IMO it is a better approach but for more advanced testng users.